# how inheritance work in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter!
I have inheritance relationship between my classes in my classdiagram. 
So, I create my custom class in library

My question is: is that necessary to create custom classes in library to convert my class diagram into code? 
if not how can I make it? thank you for your support!

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking**

Comment: @Abdulla thank you! how inheritance work in codeigniter?

Comment: explain with what you need. im out with what you trying to ask